# Why is my await not waiting for my function to finish?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have an async function with two await functions in it. The second one doesn't seem to wait for the first one.

```
submitForm(req, res) {
    /**
     * @param {Object} auth the authentication generated from authorize function.
     */
    const uploadFilesToDrive = async auth => {

        await drive.files.create(
            {
                resource: folderMetadata,
                fields: "id"
            },
            (err, folder) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    for (let elem in req.files) {
                        file = bufferToStream(req.files[elem][0].buffer);
                        fileName = req.files[elem][0].originalname;
                        mimeType = req.files[elem][0].mimetype;

                        fileMetadata = {
                            name: fileName,
                            parents: [folder.data.id]
                        };
                        media = {
                            mimeType,
                            body: file
                        };
                        drive.files.create(
                            {
                                resource: fileMetadata,
                                media,
                                fields: "id"
                            },
                            (err, file) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                } else {
                                    form[
                                        req.files[elem][0].fieldname
                                    ] = `https://drive.google.com/open?id=${file.data.id}`;
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        );


        await Form.create(form)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                    message: err
                });
            })
            .then(form => {
                res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).json({
                    message: "Form submitted successfully",
                    form
                });
            });
    };

    loadDriveSecret(uploadFilesToDrive);
}
```

I tried to create a promise for the first function `await new Promise((resolve, reject) => drive.files.create(...` and resolve it immediately after the loop `for (let elem in req.files) {...}}return resolve();`, but that still didn't wait. I used the console and saw that the first function would resolve immediately and go to the next function, while the for loop is still running.

Comment: Since `drives.files.create` inside the callback is also async, you'd also have to await those (which you might need to promisify). You can achieve this with `Promise.all([…])`

Comment: `drive.files.create(err, folder)` is a callback function not an async/promise function.  You don't need to use promises/async as the code will return once the execution finished.